# Native query with like operator fails after migrating to spring6 (hibernate6 )

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-6.x

Before migration to spring6 following query used to work :

```java
@Query(value="select id,name,email from table1 where name like %:userName% ",nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> getUserDetails(@Param("userName")String userName);
```

Post migration to spring6 (hibernate 6), we will have to embed the like operator with single quote to make the query work :

```sql
@Query(value="select id,name,email from table1 where name like '%:userName%' ",nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> getUserDetails(@Param("userName")String userName);
```

I enabled the debug logs of Hibernate and found the following

Before migration the query generated looks like this :

```
where name like ?
```

Post migration the query that is generated looks like :

```
where name like CONCAT('%',?,'%')
```

and above query execution fails with following error

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 909, SQLState: 42000
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
```

My upgraded maven has following versions :

spring boot : 3.1.0

hibernate core : 6.2.2.Final

I wanted to check if this is a bug or we are expected to update our native queries.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue.. any solution to this? Pls help

Comment: @MananKapoor I couldn't find the reason yet. However, as I have mentioned in the question, we can embed the like operator within single quotes. This will work, but we don't know if it Is the official migration change.

Comment: Thank you! As per your mention, it worked for me.